# SQL, operation between paired rows

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have a table t1

```
a   b
1   4
2   2
3   9
2   1
1   6
3   7
```

I need the output

```
a   result
1   4*6
2   2*1
3   9*7
```

I have been able to do it in a far from efficient way and would like a more satisfactory way. Thank you.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: If you are using Postgres, you can easily create your own aggregate for that. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=00a9efeb913257f4851e2b966483320b

Comment: Currently MariaDB, but @a_horse_with_no_name is helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want a floating point result, and you can have more than 2 `b` values for each `a` value, you can use a recursive CTE to generate the results:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE t1r AS (
  SELECT *, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a) AS rn
  FROM t1
),
maxrows AS (
  SELECT a, MAX(rn) AS maxrow
  FROM t1r
  GROUP BY a
),
mul AS (
  SELECT a, b AS result, rn, rn AS maxrow
  FROM t1r
  WHERE rn = 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT mul.a, result * b, t1r.rn, t1r.rn
  FROM mul
  JOIN t1r ON t1r.a = mul.a AND t1r.rn = mul.rn + 1
)
SELECT mul.a, mul.result
FROM mul
JOIN maxrows mr ON mr.a = mul.a AND mr.maxrow = mul.rn
ORDER BY mul.a
```

Output:

```
a   result
1   24
2   2
3   63
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=35295b0c70a73c604d760b43789ee742)

Note that this could be simplified if there was a column by which you could order the rows, that would remove the need to have the `maxrows` CTE.

Answer (score 1):

You can use logs and exponents.  Depending on your database the exact functions might vary, but something like this:

```
select a, exp(sum(ln(b))) as product
from t
group by a;
```

If you have only two values, you could also use:

```
select a, min(b) * max(b) as product
from t
group by a;
```

Comment: This is a great solution if a floating point answer is acceptable.  The solutions for integer answers are all going to be much more complicated and slower.